# docker push into private Docker registry inside Kubernetes cluster fails with: 413 Request Entity Too Large

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, docker-registry

I have deployed a private Docker registry (image `registry:2`) in a Kubernetes cluster and exposed it via an `Ingress`. I am using the `nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress` (not: `kubernetes/ingress-nginx`) [NGINX ingress controller](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/blob/master/docs/nginx-ingress-controllers.md).

`curl https://my_registry/v2/_catalog` works fine. But `docker push` into the registry runs into this error: `Pushing` ... `100.6MB/100.6MB` ... `413 Request Entity Too Large`.

For what I know, this can be mitigated by instructing the NGINX ingres controller to accept larger chunks of data. I have e.g. tried adding the annotation `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "200m"` into my `Ingress` specification (as suggested [here](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/issues/21)) but this has not worked so far.

So what is the right way for instructing an `nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress` NGINX ingress controller to accept sufficiently large chunks?

**UPDATE** I have meanwhile [concluded](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/pull/33) that `nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress` does not take its configuration from annotations, but from a `ConfigMap` named `nginx-config` that resides in the same namespace as the NGINX ingress controller. I have now added such a `ConfigMap` with `data` `client-max-body-size: "200m"`, but the problem still persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have switched from [NGINX Inc.'s](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress) to [Kubernetes'](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx) NGINX ingress controller, and there adding the following annotation to the `Ingress`' `metadata` proved sufficient:

```
annotations:
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 500m
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set Annotation:

```
nginx.org/client-max-body-size "200m"
```

Comment: You can try my updated comment, also did you restart pod after changed configmap